# Plugin config checkbox, setting default=true breaks it

Tags: plugin, configuration

In a plugin config xml file, the following creates a config checkbox fine:

```
<field name="post_allowed" type="checkbox"
  default="0"
  description="Post Allowed"
  label="Post Allowed"
/>
```

However if I change the default to 1, it breaks to config screen. It becomes impossible to uncheck the it:

```
<field name="post_allowed" type="checkbox"
  default="1"
  description="Post Allowed"
  label="Post Allowed"
/>
```

Comment: I've just tested your exact code and it works fine for me. What version of Joomla are you using? And are you using the latest version of your build?

Comment: Joomla! 3.3.6 pretty recent. Unchecking, saving, refreshing leaves to box checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that deselecting post_allowed and then submitting the form will not submit any value for post_allowed.

So if you had the plugin's post_allowed value stored as 1 in the database, then you edit the plugin options page, deselect the checkbox and press save, no data is sent for post_allowed and thus the original value of 1 is not replaced.

I would suggest replacing the checkbox with a radio button:

```
<field name="post_allowed" type="radio"
  class="btn-group"
  default="1"
  description="Post Allowed"
  label="Post Allowed">
    <option value="0">JNO</option>
    <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>
```